# How to refresh FutureProvider without showing loading indicator again in Flutter with Riverpod?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, riverpod

Currently I am refreshing a FutureProvider that is responsible for fetching data from Firebase and displaying it in a simple ListView with [liquid_pull_to_refresh](https://pub.dev/packages/liquid_pull_to_refresh) package, which causes the list to disappear, the loading indicator is shown again and in the end the list is shown again.

What I would like to achieve instead is to keep the list displayed and only update it after the fetching is complete. I am using Riverpod for state management.

The provider:

```
final userProfileProvider = FutureProvider.family<FullUserModel?, String?>((ref, value) => ref.read(databaseServiceProvider).getFullUserModel(value));
```

Refresh part:

```
LiquidPullToRefresh(
  onRefresh: () async {
    ref.refresh(userProfileProvider(uid));
  },
  child: ListView()
)
```

Is there any good approach for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is no longer an issue as Riverpod 2.0+ has new refresh behaviour. It now returns the previous data/error value while loading.

> After a provider has emitted an AsyncValue.data or AsyncValue.error, that provider will no longer emit an AsyncValue.loading.
> Instead, it will re-emit the latest value, but with the property AsyncValue.isRefreshing to true.
>
> **This allows the UI to keep showing the previous data/error when a provider is being refreshed.**

If you wish to selectively show a loading indicator or some other element while the data is being refreshed, you can simply lookup the boolean value of `AsyncValue.isRefreshing`.

[Source](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod/versions/2.0.0-dev.5/changelog#200-dev0)

Comment: how to show progress dialog on loading?

Comment: If you're talking about the initial loading then you can simply use the `.when` syntax to handle the error, loading and data states as you wish.

If you're talking about reloading (loading occurring after the provider has already emitted an AsyncValue.data or AsyncValue.error), you can choose to show the progress dialog if `AsyncValue.isRefreshing==true`.

Comment: If you want to treat refreshing as loading pass `skipLoadingOnRefresh: false` to AsyncValue.when as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it's a good approach but i've made a example of what i 've done to do this:

Widgets :

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
        child: TimeDisplayer(),
      )),
    );
  }
}

class TimeDisplayer extends ConsumerWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final time = ref.watch(ref.watch(diplayedTimer));

    return Column(
      children: [
        time.when(data: (data)=>Text(data.toString()), error: (e,_)=>Text(e.toString()), loading: ()=>CircularProgressIndicator()),
        IconButton(onPressed: ()=>ref.refresh(timeRefreshProvider), icon: Icon(Icons.refresh))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Providers :

```
final timeRefreshProvider = FutureProvider<DateTime>((ref) async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
  return DateTime.now();
});

final diplayedTimer = Provider<StateProvider<AsyncValue<DateTime>>>((ref) {
  final _diplayedTimer = StateProvider<AsyncValue<DateTime>>((ref) {
    return const AsyncLoading();
  });
  ref.listen(timeRefreshProvider, (previous, next) {
    if (next is AsyncData<DateTime>) {
      ref.read(_diplayedTimer.state).update((state) => next);
    }
  });
  return _diplayedTimer;
});
```