# Flutter Riverpod show CircularProgressIndicator while waiting for future ro resolve

Tags: flutter, flutter-riverpod

I want to show CircularProgressIndicator while waiting for future to resolve using flutter_riverpod, here is my code snippet.
But it's not showing, I am using ConsumerStatefulWidget is this right way to do it?

```
ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      rejectResponse = ref
                          .read(notificationRepositoryProvider)
                          .approveDocument(1);
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                    child: FutureBuilder(
                        future: rejectResponse,
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                              ConnectionState.done) {
                            if (snapshot.hasData) {
                              return Text('Yes');
                            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                              return Text('Error');
                            }
                          } else if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                              ConnectionState.waiting) {
                            return CircularProgressIndicator();
                          }
                          return Text('Yes');
                        }),
                  ),
```

Comment: Please remove riverpod from tags and your title.  This is not a riverpod question, except that you're using a provider to hold the singleton of your repository.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way of doing this in Riverpod is using a [FutureProvider](https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/future_provider) and [AsyncValue](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/AsyncValue-class.html):

```
final notificationRepositoryProvider = FutureProvider<bool?>((ref) async {
  Future<bool> approveDocument() => Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => Future.value(Random().nextBool()));

  return approveDocument();
});

class HomeView extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const HomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  HomeViewState createState() => HomeViewState();
}

class HomeViewState extends ConsumerState<HomeView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AsyncValue<bool?> rejectResponse = ref.watch(notificationRepositoryProvider);
    return ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
         ref.refresh(notificationRepositoryProvider.future);
        },
        child: rejectResponse.when(
          loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          skipLoadingOnRefresh: false,
          error: (err, stack) => Text('Error'),
          data: (data) => Text('Yes: $data'),
        ));
  }
}
```

Note that after the initial loading, the FutureProvider will [return the previous value but will set AsyncValue.isRefreshing to true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74770245/12806961). To avoid this and always show the loader on refresh, you can set `skipLoadingOnRefresh` to false.

Comment: Thanks Joe, this is what I am looking for but I am using family provider wich takes input parameters:
final approveNotificationProvider =
    FutureProvider.autoDispose.family<Response, int>((ref, notificationId) {
  var notificationRepository = ref.watch(notificationRepositoryProvider);
  return notificationRepository.approveDocument(notificationId);
});

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ConnectionState`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ConnectionState.html), but I think it can also be in `none` state. So you can check if its done, and if not, you should probably show the loading indicator anyway.

```dart
builder: (context, snapshot) {
   if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
   } 
   else 
      return Text('Yes');
   } 
}
```

I usually use the `hasData` property instead. This lets me reduce the number of states I have to deal with, and safely assume `snapshot.data` is not `null`. I use the below pattern.

```dart
// strongly type the builder so snapshot.data is typed as well.
FutureBuilder<MyType>( 
    future: myFuture
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
       if (!snapshot.hasData) return Loading();

       final data = snapshot.data!; // '!' is safe since hasData is true
       return DisplayData(data);
    }
)
```